# How to get the count of occurence by a given range of a values in a perticular column in a data frame in R?

Tags: r, subset, plyr

My dataframe is as follows:

```
ds <- c("ab", "ab", "cd", "ab", NA, "gh")
member1age<-c(9, 21, 39, NA, 69, 90)
member1gender<-c(1,2,1,1,2,NA)
member2age<-c(15,30, 60, 21,12, 45)
member2gender<-c(1,2,2,1,2,1)
member3age<-c(17,2,90,NA,31,5)
member3gender<-c(1,1,2,NA, 1,2)
member4age<-c(NA, NA,23, NA,NA,NA)
member4gender<-c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA)

df <- data.frame(ds,member1age,member1gender,member2age,member2gender,member3age,member3gender,member4age,member4gender)
```

I want to find out how many individuals,are   there in each gender for the given age ranges in a perticular ds.

For example how many males between age 15-30 for ds- "ab".
What i want as the output is something like the following; Table A:

```
Age Category    Number of Males %   Number of Females   %   Total Number %
Below 5                 1    20.00             0     -          1      14.29 
6-14                    1    20.00             0     -          1      14.29 
15-30                   3    60.00             2     100.00     5      71.43 
31-45                   0    -                 0     -          0      -   
46-60                   0    -                 0     -          0      -   
> 60                    0    -                 0     -          0      -   
Total                   5    100.00            2     100.00     7      100.00
```

what i have tried so far is

for each of memberage column applied the following;

```
forage1<-data.frame(ddply(df, .(ds), summarize,
                      All=length(ds),
                      of6Age=sum(Age1<6),
                      of6.15Age=sum(Age1>=6 & Age1<15),
                      of15.31Age=sum(Age1>=15 & Age1<31),
                      of31.46Age=sum(Age1>=31 & Age1<46),
                      of46.60Age=sum(Age1>=46 & Age1<=60),
                      of60Age=sum(Age1>60)))
```

And then merged the data frames together as follows;
    mylist<-list(forage1, forage2, forage3,forage4, forage5, forage6, forage7, forage8)
    f1<-ldply(mylist, rbind)

However this is not what i supposed to get.What i want is the Table A mentioned above. Please enlighten me with your kind support...
Thank you in advance...!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first build your data in a proper way:

```
df <- data.frame(ds = rep(ds,4),
                 age = c(member1age,member2age,member3age, member4age),   
                 gender = c(member1gender,member2gender,member3gender,member4gender))
```

Then use `cut` to classify your population age:

```
df$AgeCategory = cut(df$age, 
                     breaks=c(-1,5,14,30,45,60,Inf), 
                     labels=c('Below 5','6-14','15-30','31-45','46-60','>60'),
                     right=T)
```

Finally summarise - here I use `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
```

Then the data frame df has to be converted to a data table

```
df = setDT(df)
```

After that

```
dt = setkey(dt, AgeCategory, ds)
dt = dt[!is.na(ds) & !is.na(AgeCategory)]      #not interested by NA in these columns
dt = dt[CJ(unique(AgeCategory),unique(ds)), allow.cartesian=T][is.na(gender), gender:=0]

dt[ds=='ab', list(MaleNumber=sum(gender==1), FemaleNumber=sum(gender==2)),AgeCategory][
   ,c('MaleRatio', 'FemaleRatio'):=list(MaleNumber/sum(MaleNumber), 
                                        FemaleNumber/sum(FemaleNumber))][]

#   AgeCategory MaleNumber FemaleNumber MaleRatio FemaleRatio
#1:     Below 5          1            0       0.2           0
#2:        6-14          1            0       0.2           0
#3:       15-30          3            2       0.6           1
#4:       31-45          0            0       0.0           0
#5:       46-60          0            0       0.0           0
#6:         >60          0            0       0.0           0
```

Comment: Thank you very much dear Mr.Colonel...the code is giving me the expected results. Thank you again for your immediate support...

Comment: if the answer helps consider accepting it/upvoting to close the topic! no worries, the question was not so straghtforward!

Comment: Sure! How ever theres another concern..hope you can support me with that as well. the results are shown in the console in the way i wanted. But when i view(dt) the result is stored in a different manner.when i write the "dt" data table to an excel file it dosen't give it in the exact way as shown in the console. How can i get the values in to a data frame as it is, as same as shown in the console  window. Sorting and filtering is time consuming since there are a  pretty large number of data files.hope you can support me...thank you !!!

Comment: you can wrap the result in `data.frame(...)`

Comment: `na.omit(dt, cols = c("ds", "AgeCategory"))` is another way to remove NAs. `CJ` also has a `unique=` argument. I'd add `by=` to make it explicit as to where the grouping is provided..

Comment: Another question  related to the above question has arrived. please tell me more.about ->                           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914836/why-data-frame-dosent-parse-the-data-frames-arguments

Answer (score 0):

First convert your `df` into a long format

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
long <- df %>% 
  add_rownames("id") %>% 
  gather(complex, value, -ds, -id) %>% 
  extract(
    complex, 
    c("member", "type"), 
    "([[:alpha:]]+[[:digit:]])([[:alpha:]]+)"
  ) %>%
  spread(type, value)
```

Then use `cut()` to split the age into groups

```
long %>%
  mutate(
    gender = factor(
      gender, 
      levels = c(1, 2), 
      labels = c("male", "female")
    ), 
    fAge = cut(age, c(0, 5, 14, 30, 45, 60, 100))
  ) %>%
  filter(!is.na(fAge), !is.na(gender)) %>%
  group_by(fAge, gender) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  spread(gender, count, fill = 0)
```